# 90's live-action TV show featuring teens in a spaceship, spaceship's captain is a teenager but his Earth parents don't know

Tags: story-identification, tv

I've been trying to find the name of this live-action TV series for years.

I used to watch it on French TV during the 90s. The show is probably American. It was about a team of teenagers/kids doing missions in space. I think most of the action would happen in the spaceship, not much exploring or space battles, but I might be wrong.

The main character, who was the captain of the ship was living a double life:
1) spaceship's captain
2) teenager having dinner with his family on Earth without them knowing about his other life. I think he would get on the spaceship by teleportation.

In one of the episodes the bad guys are messing with the captain's timeline so he starts fading away...

The opening was kinda rocky with lyrics sung by a man.

Comment: Deepwater Black/Mission Genesis? - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater Black I haven't seen it but the description of the first book reminded me of this search: "Suddenly, Robbie Mikkelson has a problem.

A dream-state called prexing is zapping him across time and space. Is he a school kid on Earth? Or is he thousands of years in the future, on a giant spaceship called Deepwater?"

Comment: Nope. The show I'm looking for was definetely more laid back ! With younger protagonists I think. Thanks for trying, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it A.J.’s Time Travelers?

He gets a ring and by saying knowledge is power at the computer screen he gets teleported to the spaceship.

At the end of each episode he has to answer 3 questions.

[image]

Comment: You nailed it !

I can definitely recognize the opening. Not sure I would have been able to find this on my own.

Don't remember time travelling was so commonly used in it. Sadly, this show seems to have gone forgotten.

Thank you bro, you're putting an end to more than a decade of searching...