# 90s sci-fi series: at the beginning a teen falls through a hole into a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship, space

I'm looking for a sci-fi series I watched in the 90s that at the beginning a teen fell through a hole in the sand into a spaceship.

Later on a group is formed called the children of something that I don't remember. I know that at some point in the series there's an Egyptian theme where they discover that a pharaoh was also one of that group called the children.

Comment: This is quite brief can you remember anything else about it? Any story elements that happen, specific plot lines? How many are in the group? How long were the episodes etc. If you remember anything else you can [edit] that detail into the question itself.

Comment: cartoon or live action series? What was the team composed of? How many children?

Comment: It's a live series, I think the group is of 5-6 teens. I remember from the Egyptian episodes that there's some kind of painting I don't know if on paper or in stone regarding space

Comment: This one doesn't have an answer either: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229456/90s-live-action-tv-show-featuring-teens-in-a-spaceship-spaceships-captain-is

Comment: While I think you have your answer, just mentioning https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102433/trying-to-find-a-movie-about-a-boy-who-finds-a-buried-spaceship-that-then-takes/138850#138850 to add it to the linked questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could this be the 1990s reboot of "[The Tomorrow People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tomorrow_People#1990s_series)"? The first episode had Adam Newman (played by Kristian Schmid) falling into a spaceship that was buried on a beach in the South Pacific. As in the 1970s original, it dealt with the adventures of a group of adolescent children, with various psychic powers.

The third season of the show started with "[The Rameses Connection](https://thetomorrowpeople.fandom.com/wiki/The_Rameses_Connection)", which featured an Egyptian pharaoh calling to the children across time, similar to the OP's recollection.

Comment: It's the tomorrow people!!!! Thank you I already checked on YouTube and this is it, I haven't seen this series in over a decade